# Does modding or using console commands disable Steam achievements for Fallout 4?

Tags: steam, achievements, fallout-4

Fallout 4 mods are starting to pour in over at [Nexus Mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/?). If I install a mod or enter a console command, will Steam achievements for the game be disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using console commands **does not** disable achievements through steam. I've used a console command to place enemy NPCs and the like such as togglegodmode and togglecollision and I still get in-game achievements through steam. Installing mods will most likely not alter the achievements either

Comment: Actually, from what I understand, using mods will disable achievements, but then there is another mod that will allow you to get achievements with a modded game. Source for mods disabling achievements: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164593-fallout-4/73897006. Source for mod that enables achievements again: http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/12465/?

Comment: @Nzall - Awesome thanks, that saves me a headache haha. Would you care to put that into an answer on it's own? :-)